# variable within a function seems not to be local

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables, rename, deque

I writing a program that takes an initial sequence and performs 3 functions on it and then spits out the 3 answers but I want to keep the original variable intact so it can be reused. From [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them) on the forum I have concluded that the variable within a function should be local but it appears to be acting globally.

```
from collections import deque
from sys import exit
initial_state = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
initial_state = deque(initial_state)

def row_exchange(t):
    t.reverse()
    return t
def rt_circ_shift(t):
    t.appendleft(t[3])
    del t[4]
    t.append(t[4])
    del t[4]
    return t
def md_clk_rot (t):
    t.insert(1,t[6])
    del t[7]
    t.insert(3,t[4])
    del t[5]
    t.insert(4,t[5])
    del t[6]
    return t



print(row_exchange(initial_state))
print(initial_state)
print(rt_circ_shift(initial_state))
print(md_clk_rot(initial_state))
```

I would expect to get:

```
deque([8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
deque([4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5])
deque([1, 7, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 8])
```

but instead I get:

```
deque([8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
deque([8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
deque([5, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4])
deque([5, 1, 8, 6, 3, 7, 2, 4])
```

so why isn't my variable local within the function?
is there a way I can rename the output within the function so that it isn't using the same identifier initial_state?
I'm pretty new to programming so over explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs for deque.reverse](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.deque.reverse):

> Reverse the elements of the deque **in-place** and then return None.

(my emphasis). Therefore

```
def row_exchange(t):
    t.reverse()
    return t

row_exchange(initial_state)
```

modifies `initial_state`. Note that `append`, `appendleft` and `insert` also modify the `deque` in-place.

---

To reverse without modifying `t` inplace, you could use

```
def row_exchange(t):
    return deque(reversed(t))
```

---

In each of the functions, `t` is a local variable. The effect you are seeing is
not because `t` is somehow global -- it is not. Indeed, you would get a
`NameError` if you tried to reference `t` in the global scope.

---

For more on why modifying a local variable can affect a value outside the local scope, see Ned Batchelder's [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). In particular, look at the discussion of the function `augment_twice`.